# Can Cloud Workflows be used for both orchestration AND transformation?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-camel, integration, serverless, ipaas

I hope you guys are doing well.

We are evaluating some solutions (Apache Camel K and the likes) to allow teams to:

- Low Code protocol transformation (Kafka, FTP, S3, MQ, SOAP, SFTP, gRPC, GraphQL, etc.) One team in particular has to integrate their product with 100s of external partners (each one uses a different integration technology), and writing each integration "by hand" would be a waste of time/motivation.
- Enrich integrations' payloads (by calling both internal and external services)
- **Pay per execution/transformation/step (SERVERLESS)**
- **Orchestrate processes that span multiples domain/services (On either our GCP account or Partners external Datacenters)**
- Strong retry and monitoring capabilities
- Be part of our CI/CD pipeline (and not be limited to a Graphical interface)

The items in bold seem to be part of what Cloud Workflows does natively, but are the other requirements something that can be added to (or achieved with) GCW to keep it "serverless"? Please.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cloud Workflow can perform basic transformation (on string or date), but I can't recommend that. It's better to have a Cloud Functions or a Cloud Run that perform a transformation with code. You will be able to write unit test on it and to ensure the quality and the evolution of your system without regressions.

For orchestration, it's the purpose of Cloud Workflows. Now, there is also some limits, or some corner case less easy to achieve with it. It depends on the complexity of your process and your expectations (observability, portability, replayability,...)